# Seeking for correlations between combination of variables

Tags: r, correlation

I have a data set with plant measurements and indices as columns. 
I would like to see the correlations between the indices and measurements to see if any indices could help to predict the value of some measurement. I performed a simple `corrplot` in R but the results show no particular correlation.

Thus, I would like to try to see if any measurement could have a high correlation (let's arbitrary say > 0.9) with the combination of two (or more) indices. Is there a way to automate that search process in R ?

Comment: How many "measurement" variables do you have? Are you interested in getting combination of indices only or are you interested also in combinations of the measurement variables?

Comment: I have 39 measurements and 45 indices. Only in combination of indices.

Comment: This seems like a situation where the lasso might work.

Comment: Could you explain what is the lasso ?